# Strange expression found in my Java code: variable assignment syntax

Tags: java, variables, declaration

Somewhere in my code today, I found that I had written the following line

```
JsonArray environmentJsonArray = new JsonArray(), playerJsonArray, teamJsonArray;
```

I am at a complete loss in understanding how this is even working. The basic question is, What are the two variables on my RHS ? I checked if I had declared them before, but I did not. The compiler still does not complain apparently indicating that the variables `playerJsonArray` and `teamJsonArray` were taken as fresh declarations. But then the declared variables are always on the LHS. Isn't that so? Has something changed in Java's basic syntax? Iam trying to go through the specifications to get to the bottom but just in case anyone has a quicker understanding please.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Just relating this back to how PMD can help me avoid writing such confusing code;

Comment: I don't think PMD can help much. That's just common sense not to write code like that.

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring 3 variables of type `JsonArray`, and only assigning an initial value to the first.

It's basically the same as:

```
JsonArray environmentJsonArray = new JsonArray();
JsonArray playerJsonArray;
JsonArray teamJsonArray;
```

The relevant section of JLS 9 is [Sec 14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).

> Has something changed in Java's basic syntax?

It has been like this since [version 1.0](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/14.doc.html#5920).

Comment: How can I use PMD rules to check this and avoid being repeated?

Comment: No idea, I don't use PMD.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to declaring 3 variables whose type is JsonArray also you only initialize the first one which is environmentJsonArray. The remaining ones which are playerJsonArray, teamJsonArray are the uninitialized ones.